# Wheels not rotating in Rigacar rig

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

When I move the car rig with  <kbd>G</kbd> shortcut then the wheels do not move. everything else like drift and all works perfects also the direction of wheels is changing but they are not rotating.

[image]

Comment: pasteall.org didnt allow me to add a 24mb+ file so i used another website... anyway u can get the file in my question i have edited it. thanksss

Comment: so do you know how it is supposed to work? what bone is supposed to make the wheel rotate etc?

Comment: ummm nope actually i just renamed all the wheels brakes and body 

Comment: the wheels could have a constraint > Transformation for example, it will make them rotate as the armature moves in the 3D space. For the rotation you could use a Copy Rotation constraint but you say that they already rotate correctly?

Comment: they dont rotate but they steer correctly and yeah ik about contraints

Comment: the rotation is only the problems rest rig is working perfectly

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I guess you need to try a Transformation constraint, have you looked into that?

Comment: sure @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i will take care from next time

Comment: yeah i was trying to get it work with the contraint only

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the [Rigacar addon's documentation](http://digicreatures.net/articles/rigacar.html):

> The animation rig can rotate wheels as you move your model along the Y
> axis.
>
> [image: rigacar GUI]
>
> Activating the rotation of the wheels for motion along the Y axis Be
> aware the spinning is only correct for translation on the Y axis. So,
> this feature is not the proper way to animate wheels with Rigacar (see
> section below). But it is useful to quickly check the generated rig.
> In the properties panel, put the property Wheels on Y axis to 1 to
> activate this feature. Don't forget to set it back to 0 once you have
> checked your model.

TL;DR:

Make sure you have [the addon](https://github.com/digicreatures/rigacar/releases/latest) installed and enabled.
In the viewport's sidebar, RigaCar tab, set the "Wheels on Y axis" to 1 when you whant the wheels to automatically roll.